# Find a set of characters in a string C# class file(.cs)

Tags: c#, regex, string

I'm working on a Existing Class file(.cs) which fetches a string with some data in it.
I need to check if the string contains a word. *String has no blank spaces in it.*

The string-

```
"<t>StartTxn</t><l>0</l><s>0</s><u>1</u><r>0</r><g>1</g><t>ReleaseUserAuthPending</t>"
```

I need to check if the string contains **'ReleaseUserAuthPending'** in it.

Comment: Use `.Contains()` or a regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
var strValue = "<t>StartTxn</t><l>0</l><s>0</s><u>1</u><r>0</r><g>1</g><t>ReleaseUserAuthPending</t>";
if (strValue.Contains("ReleaseUserAuthPending"))
{
    //Do stuff
}
```

Refer [About String - Contains function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx)

**For your information:** `Contains` function is *case-sensitive*. If you want to make this `Contains` function as *case-insensitive*. Do the following step from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444798/case-insensitive-containsstring) link.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool containsString = mystring.Contains("ReleaseUserAuthPending");
```

Comment: It would be better to explain why this is the correct answer, not just provide some code.

Comment: It's not self documenting enough for you?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
String yourString = "<t>StartTxn</t><l>0</l><s>0</s><u>1</u><r>0</r><g>1</g><t>ReleaseUserAuthPending</t>";
if(yourString.Contains("ReleaseUserAuthPending")){
      //contains ReleaseUserAuthPending
}else{
     //does not contain ReleaseUserAuthPending
}
```